# Is writing "Hire me to do this job" a right comment?

Tags: discussion

Often I came across questions where I think the user is asking too much, either as humor or serious, can I say "Hire me to do this job".

Will it be acceptable for the community and with the moderators?

Comment: Well, the number one thing to do is to cast a close vote pointing at the question being too broad.

Comment: I want to say no, this is not acceptable. This is a Q&A site and fishing for clients is not something we would want to encourage. I need to stew on this more for a better more formulated answer as well as looking over SE TOS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't consider fishing for clients like that as an acceptable answer or comment. As the question asker, that is extremely rude, tongue in cheek or not. You are basically coming off as condescending. If the question is too broad, flag it as such so it can be acted on, or leave a suggestion on focusing the question.

From a community perspective, we have striven to keep a lot of the third party stuff out of the site so it is purely SharePoint people, helping SharePoint users, with their SharePoint problems. Interjecting sales pitches could be considered advertising, and we've taken a hard line about deleting those posts and comments and squashing those user accounts.

If you are considering fishing for clients in that fashion, contact the stackoverflow folks for ad pricing information, or visit their [advertising info page](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit).

Comment: +1 Completely agree! (I'm a little too diplomatic in my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

When you have 10k+ on this site, you are really stating that you can be hired to do any job related to SharePoint. Even if you don’t know the answer by heart, you have the proven knowledge that you can evaluate suggested solutions. You just have to make sure that you reference contact info on your profile page so that users can reach out to you. I use Twitter and Linked In, publicly visible.

But writing “Hire me to do the job” is a little “in your face”-comment, which should be avoided. Instead flag the question as too broad which says exactly what we mean. If it is a serious question, the user will edit, if not – the user will abandon the question. You can also comment by asking the user to narrow the scope of the question, if you feel it’s worth the time.

[image]

Comment: I will politely disagree with 10K+ reputation and people know that you know your stuff. It's like if a company has enough reputation in the market, they don't approach to new customers, don't spend a penny on marketing, since people already know that the company knows their stuff. However marking it as too broad is okay.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri As you already know, being a 10k+ user, advertisement is paied for - not something that comes in a comment, I politely reply.